# I cannot get my program to work. I think it may be an issue with naming, but I'm not sure. What do I do?

Tags: c#

I'm making a program that takes a .txt file, reads it, and then shows the average score, above average score, and below average score. There are no syntax errors, but nothing seems to get it to work. Clicking the button does nothing.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace The_Score_List_V2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ReadScores(List<int> scoreList)
        {
            try
            {
                StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText("TestScores.txt");

                while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    scoreList.Add(int.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine()));
                }

                inputFile.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void DisplayScores(List<int> scoreList)
        {
            foreach (int score in scoreList)
            {
                this.scoreList.Items.Add(score);
            }
        }

        private double average(List<int> scoreList)
        {
            int total = 0;
            double average;

            foreach (int score in scoreList)
            {
                total += score;
            }

            average = (double)total / scoreList.Count;

            return average;
        }

        private int AboveAverage(List<int> scoreList)
        {
            int numAbove = 0;

            double avg = average(scoreList);

            foreach (int score in scoreList)
            {
                if (score > avg)
                {
                    numAbove++;
                }
            }

            return numAbove;
        }

        private int BelowAverage(List<int> scoreList)
        {
            int numBelow = 0;

            double avg = average(scoreList);

            foreach (int score in scoreList)
            {
                if (score < avg)
                {
                    numBelow++;
                }
            }

            return numBelow;
        }

        private void getScoresButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double averageScore;
            int numAboveAverage;
            int numBelowAverage;

            List<int> scoreList = new List<int>();

            ReadScores(scoreList);

            DisplayScores(scoreList);

            averageScore = average(scoreList);
            averageLabel.Text = averageScore.ToString("n1");

            numAboveAverage = AboveAverage(scoreList);
            this.numAboveAverage.Text = numAboveAverage.ToString();

            numBelowAverage = BelowAverage(scoreList);
            this.numBelowAverage.Text = numBelowAverage.ToString();
        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Also [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkJrE.jpg) are the names from design view to show that it isn't a hook up issue. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure that you have associated the handlers with the controls? If you go to the events property tab for getScoresButton, is the click event set to getScoresButton_Click?

Comment: Did you manually type the click event - or did you assign it through the event properties? Or by double clicking the button in design view?

Comment: You may have scope issues with `scoreList`. To make your code clearer, so you know you're referencing what you intend, you should give your variables different names.

Comment: I added the button through double clicking on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and it ran fine - once I had the file path correct. I believe that your problem is that the **TestScores.txt** file is not located in the same folder in which your code is running.

If you are doing this for a learning experience, I suggest you specify the full path of the file. Otherwise, you might want to use an **OpenFileDialog** object so that you can specify the file during runtime. Microsoft's Developer Network has a good article [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also, if you want to use this for production, consider using the **int.TryParse()** method instead of **int.Parse()** so that you can handle the bad data often found in text files.